# Matching only 1st occurence of any character

Tags: regex

I want to know how to match just the 1st character occurrence using regex

Output

```
    # Address 
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.UnlockCode:YR\\FKNT5ST3WCM:\\1J4JTCQQMH/H
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.DatabasePath:C:/AddressDoctor
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.Optimization:ADDRESSES_SORTED_BY_COUNTRIES
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.MemoryMB:600
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.CorrectionType:CORRECT_ONLY
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.PreLoad.CERTIFIED.PRELOAD_PART:US
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.PreLoad.CERTIFIED.PRELOAD_FULL:
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.PreLoad.CORRECTION_ONLY.PRELOAD_PART:CA, US
cleanse.library.addressDoctor.AddressDoctor.PreLoad.CORRECTION_ONLY.PRELOAD_FULL:
```

In this case I want to match just `:` (the 1st occurrence)

**Update**

Note: `:` (1st occurrence in every line)

You can [test here](http://regexr.com?2v8h2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern:

```
^[^:]*:
```

matches the start of the input (`^`), followed by zero or more characters other than `:` (`[^:]*`) followed by a `:`.

So, this matches the first `:` (and of course everything that precedes the `:`).

So, let's say you would like to replace the first `:` with an `@`. You then simply group everything that precedes the first `:`, like this:

```
^([^:]*):
```

and replace it with:

```
$1@
```

As shown here: http://regexr.com?2v8h8

#### EDIT

Most regex implementations do not allow a pattern to match the first `:` in a line. You'd need a *variable width look-behind assertion* for such a thing, which simply is not supported by most languages.

You could read the file line by line and split on the `:` and provide a 2nd parameter that indicates the size of the array being returned:

```
array = line.split(/:/, 2)
```

Many regex implementation have such a method (I can't be more specific since I don't know the language you're using).

Comment: I just want to match `:`, so that I can separate them based on `:` something like keys and values, when I use `^[^:]*:` [here](http://regexr.com?2v8h5) it matches the whole thing before `:`

Comment: I just want to match `:`, so that I can separate them based on `:` something like keys and values in maps. Also please read my Updated Note in question

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to goto coding in this case (that's the last option, which is why i did not mention my language, it's JAVA BTW), is there any possibility it can be done using regex itself?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon, you should always include the editor or language you're using since most regex flavors have (slight) differences. But the answer whether this is possible is: no. Java does not support this (see my answer for details).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use :

```
/:/
```

This will match the first column `:`

Comment: It matches only 1st row, I want it to match all the rows, but in 1 row only the 1st occurance

Comment: It will work if you apply it on each line. You can first split the string on `\n`

Comment: Hey, check my answer, it works just like i wanted using only regex, I don't know what exactly it is doing `(?:)`, but somehow it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you applying your regex separately on each row?

If yes, then just don't use the greedy modifier. ([See on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v8he))

How you use it depends on your language, but I assume every language will have the possibility to match non greedy, i.e. stop matching after the first match.

**Edit:**

What about using capturing groups?

```
^([^:\r\n]*):(.*)$
```

See it [here on Regxr](http://regexr.com?2v8hh)

You will find the part before the first `:` in group 1 and the part behind till the end of the row in group 2.

Comment: I want it to be global, i.e., match all the lines, but 1st occurrence in every line

Comment: @AbhishekSimon I added another idea.